# JQuery: Selecting dynamically created elements and pushing to Firebase

Tags: jquery, firebase, dynamically-generated

Beginner to all of this, playing around with Firebase. Basically, I want to retrieve text entries from Firebase and have an "Approve" button next to it. When the button is clicked, I want that specific text entry to be pushed to a new Firebase location and the text removed from the page. I am creating the button and the text dynamically and I am having some trouble with selecting the button and the divs I created. I know I have to use on() but I'm unsure of how to use it.

Thanks!

```
approveRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
 var posts = snapshot.val();
 $('<div id="post">').text(posts.text).append('<button style ="button" id="approve">Approve</button>').appendTo($('#feed'));
});

$('#approve').on("click", function(){
    var text = $('#post').val();
    postsRef.push({'text':text});
    $('#post').remove();

});
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to bind `.on()` on a container of your dynamically added element that is already on the page when you load it, and have it like this:

```
$('#yourContainer').on('click', '#approve', function(){
    //your code here..
});
```

Comment: To expand, the first argument to on() is the event, the second is a "selector" which, if present, delegates the events to children of this element, even if they are added in the future

Comment: This worked for me after spending 3+ hours looking for this hack! You sir deserve a medal!

Comment: Now, how do you do that if you have a bunch of links, and you need to .each them?

Answer (score 16):

Your `.on()` didn't work, because you are adding the button dynamically. You can't find the dynamically added elements directly using that elements id selector like `$('#approve')`. So you should
bind `.on()` with `$(document)` selector. This will always contain your dynamically added elements.

`$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );`

```
$(document).on('click','#approve',function(){
//your code here
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I find a quick dip into the DOM, and then running back into jQuery very handy for this problem:

```
// Construct some new DOM element.
$(whatever).html('... id="mynewthing"...');

// This won't work...
$("#mynewthing")...

// But this will...
$(document.getElementById("mynewthing"))...
```

This works by [turning the DOM object directly into a selector](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-elements-when-i-already-have-a-dom-element/). I like it because the approach is transparent in operation/intent.

Comment: $(document.getElementById("mynewthing"))... with capital i

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative, simpler to understand, less powerful, also perfectly valid, is to simply bind the event while you create the element:

```
approveRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
 var posts = snapshot.val();
 var $button = $('<button style ="button" id="approve">Approve</button>');
 $button.on("click", function(){
    var text = $('#post').val();
    postsRef.push({'text':text});
    $('#post').remove();
 });

 $('<div id="post">').text(posts.text).append($button).appendTo($('#feed'));
});
```

Another problem you are going to run into, assuming there will be more than one of these on a page, is that you are using IDs in the records. They're going to clash if they aren't unique.

A great alternative is to refer to these items with data-* tags or other identifying characteristics, such as css tags. But in your case, you don't need them at all!

```
approveRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
 var posts = snapshot.val();
 var id = snapshot.name();

 var $button = $('<button style="button">Approve</button>');
 $button.on("click", function(){
    // use parent.closest(...) in place of an ID here!
    var text = $(this).parent().closest('textarea').val();
    postsRef.push({'text':text});
    $(this).parent().remove();
 });

 /* just an example of how to use a data-* tag; I could now refer to this element using:
    $('#feed').find('[data-record="'+id+'"]') if I needed to find it */
 $('<div data-record="'+id+'">').text(posts.text).append($button).appendTo($('#feed'));
});
```

Comment: I don't agree that this is simpler to understand, and it seems unnecessarily complex when binding the .on() command correctly will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure exactly what are you looking for. You can use .find() to select dynamically elements. I think .find() will look at the html structure again to get needed elements.

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
   $(".parentContainer").find(".dynamically-child-element").html("Hello world");
});
```

Or

```
$(".parentContainer").find(".dynamically-child-element").html("Hello world"); // not in click event
```

So this is my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hfvqys76/)