# does normal jquery id #selector work on html of an Ajax json response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

with on click event i returned the below drop down  element as ajax json response, without page refresh:

```
<select class='custom-select col-md-4' id='family'>
  <option value''> Select family</option>
  <option value='1'>familyName</option>
</select>
```

then I want to execute a function when changed the option using:

```
$('#family').on('change', function(){
        alert("Yeey");
 });
```

but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Check the console for any errors occur

Comment: You may need to update the DOM with dynamically-inserted elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561243/jquery-selecting-dynamically-created-elements-and-pushing-to-firebase

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working.
Just add one more option in select

For now, you have only one option which is by default selected so no change event applied.
your script is good.
example:

```
<select class='custom-select col-md-4' id='family'>
 <option value=''>select family</option>
  <option value='1'>familyName</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have a number of options. but still doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Did you added the jquery lib?
 Hope you did not miss to include this file. 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yes I did, in fact I'm using the same function with another select element in the same Modal, but the difference is that this one is ajax returned DOM and the other one is part of the page html structure

Comment: OKay, If its Ajax return then you have to add onchange function in HTML element,
like: <select class='custom-select col-md-4' id='family' onchange="choseFamily()">
and in your javascript make fucniton choseFamily(){},
Do'nt use id for call onchange

Answer (score 0):

Needs more than 1 option.
By default, the first option is selected.
So there's no on change event triggering.