# How To Make All Checkbox in table data loop

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make all checkbox in data table,
i try make like that code, but only one data row select.

how can i make that all seleted

and how to number "1,2,3.." when table data is added, don't start over

```
$('#pilih').click(function(){
            const unit = document.getElementById('unit').value;
            const nosam = document.getElementById('nosam').value;

            $.ajax({
                url: 'get/penjualan_data.php',
                data: {'unit': unit, 'nosam': nosam},
                cache: false,
            }).then(function(data){
                const json = data,
                obj = JSON.parse(json);

                var $table = $('#tampilkan tbody');
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        const a = i+1;
                 var $row = 
                    $("<tr>" +
            "<td>"+ a +"</td>" +
            "<td><input type='checkbox' id='check'></td>"+
                      "<td>"+ obj[i].nosam +"/"+ obj[i].gol +"</td>" +
                      "<td>"+ obj[i].nama +"</td>" +
            "<td>"+ obj[i].alamat +"</td>" +
                      "<td>"+ blnIndo(parseInt(obj[i].bulan)) +" "+ obj[i].tahun +"</td>" +
            "<td>"+  +"</td>" +
                      "<td>"+ obj[i].rupiah +"</td>" +
                      "</tr>");
          
                 $row.data(obj.nosam);
                 $row.data(obj.nama);
                 $row.data(obj.rupiah);
                 $table.append($row)
        }
            });
        });

    // only one select
    $('#checked-all').click(function(){
      $('#check').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PZqe.png)

Answer (score 1):

that because element that you want to check is dynamic element (not exist when the dom loaded), for dynamic element please read this
[JQuery: Selecting dynamically created elements and pushing to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561243/jquery-selecting-dynamically-created-elements-and-pushing-to-firebase)

OOT:
id attribute must be unique per document
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

you should use class if there is multiple element using that id

Comment: thank you,
ternyata ada suhunya indo dsini hehe makasih mas, saya pelajari dulu